# Relaciones entre tres tablas

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hola buenas tardes y feliz Domingo. Como siempre tengo problemas entre relaciones con las tablas.

**Mi tabla de users**

| id | name | foto |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nombre1 | foto.jpg |
| 1 | nombre2 | foto.jpg |

**Mi tabla clientes**

| id | centro |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | centro1 |
| 1 | centro2 |

**Mi tabla mensajes**

| id | cliente_id | mensaje | admin_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | mensaje1 | 1 |
| 1 | 10 | mensaje2 | 1 |

Como veis tengo una tabla con los clientes, y una relación para sacar los mensajes que dejo en cada cliente, pueden ser varios en un mismo cliente. Pero como podeis ver en la tabla de mensajes tengo un campo que se llama `admin_id` que es que administrador inserta el mensaje. Entonces los mensajes con relaciones los saco estupendamente, saco los mensajes que tiene un cliente sin problema, el problema es sacar la foto del administrador que esta en la tabla `users`..

**Modelo Cliente**

```
class Cliente extends Model
{
    //Aquí me conecto a los mensajes del cliente//
    public function mensajes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Mensaje', 'cliente_id');
    }
    
}
```

**Modelo Mensaje**

```
class Mensaje extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'mensajes';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    //Aquí la relación con el cliente//
    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cliente', 'id');
    }
    //Aquí intento que saque la foto//
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Modelo User**

```
protected $table = 'users';
protected $primaryKey='id';


public function mensaje()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Mensaje', 'admin_id');
}
```

Es decir un cliente puede tener muchos mensajes, y el mensaje corresponde a un cliente y a un administrador.

Una vez itero los clientes, itero así los mensajes:

```
@foreach ($clie->mensajes as $item){

@endforeach
```

Eso me devuelve esto:

```
#original: array:7 [▼
        "id" => 25
        "cliente_id" => 310
        "mensaje" => "mensaje"
        "admin_id" => 10
        "fecha" => "01/03/2021"
        "created_at" => "2021-03-01 11:32:17"
        "updated_at" => "2021-03-01 11:32:17"
      ]
```

Como puedo hacer para sacar la foto del administrador y su nombre??? Gracias...

---

La consulta en el Controlador para sacar los clientes:

```
$clientes = Cliente::join('tecnologias', 'clientes.interes', '=', 
'tecnologias.id')
->join('interes', 'clientes.interesCliente', '=', 'interes.id')
->select('clientes.*', 'tecnologias.name AS nombreEquipo', 'interes.name as nameInteres', 'interes.fondo', 'interes.color')
->whereIn('clientes.tipo_cliente', [0, 3])->get();
```

Con eso muestro los clientes en una tabla, luego itero un modal por cada uno para ver los mensajes.

---

**Prueba de iteración con la respuesta de @BetaM**

```
@foreach ($clie->mensajesDeUsuarios as $item)
   <div>{{ $item->name }}</div>
     @foreach ($item->pivot as $item2)
        <div class="stiloMensaje">{{ $item2->mensaje }}
          <div class="metadata">
           <span class="time"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

También en la tabla de mensajes hay un campo `fecha que es de donde saco la fecha de publicación del mensaje`. Por lo que vi en los modelos que creaste haces esto:

```
(Cliente::class, 'mensajes', 'admin_id', 'cliente_id')
(User::class, 'mensajes', 'cliente_id', 'admin_id')
```

Añadi el campo ahí de `fecha` pero parece que deja de existir la relación.

**El fallo de no poder iterar los mensajes, es por que ya esta iterando `mensajesDeUsuarios` entonces basta con acceder a `{{ $item->pivot->mensaje }}` y ya iterea los mensajes de forma correcta. No hacia falta iterar dos veces, bueno 3 si cuentas la que iteras al cliente.

Comment: Hola @BetaM ya la he puesto, no la puse por que con eso solo cargo una tabla con los clientes, luego en cada iteración de cada fila tengo un modal donde cargo los mensajes

Comment: Ok! saco una tabla con todos los clientes, luego itero un modal por cada uno de ellos donde cargo los mensajes, esto lo hago sin problemas, pero no se como sacar la foto del que publica el mensaje, dicha foto se guarda en la tabla `users``

Comment: Si correcto! lo vincula de ese modo

Comment: No se me da bien lo de las relaciones, es una tarea pendiente de profundizar más

Comment: Gracias es verdad, lo estaba poniendo donde no toca!

Comment: Ok ok! tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trataré de comentar un poco mas allá de la duda expuesta y posterior tratar de ofrecer una *posible solución*.

1. Las relaciones definidas lucen incorrectas desde el momento en que mensajes parece una tabla *intermedia* al estar almacenando las llaves primarias tanto de `User` como de `Cliente`
2. Dado el comentario anterior, entonces:

   - No hace falta un modelo para `Mensajes` (*salvo que tengas un requerimiento que lo justifique y de ser así entonces deberías sujetarte a las [convenciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models)*)
   - De ser así, entonces la relación que defines no es la adecuada, en cambio debes usar: [**`belongsToMany`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure) en cada una de las entidades que alimentan a la tabla *intermedia*
   - Recomiendo leas la doc. sobre el uso del método [`withPivot`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns)

Hechos los comentarios anteriores, entonces tus entidades pudieran quedar así:

**Modelo Cliente**

```
<?php 

class Cliente extends Model
{
    public function mensajesDeUsuarios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'mensajes', 'cliente_id', 'admin_id')->withPivot('mensaje');
    }
 }
```

**Modelo User**

```
<?php 

class User extends Model
{
    public function mensajesDeClientes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Cliente::class, 'mensajes', 'admin_id', 'cliente_id')->withPivot('mensaje');
    }
}
```

Ahora la consulta:

```
$usuariosConMensajes = User::with('mensajesDeClientes')->get();
```

Realiza de la misma un **`dd($usuariosConMensajes);`** para que veas la información que  te esta retornando

**Edición**

Una vez que la consulta anterior te retorna valores, deberías iterarlos de esta forma (*basado en mi ejemplo*)

Así tu consulta:

```
$clientesConMensajes = Cliente::with('mensajesDeUsuarios')->get();
```

Así lo iterarías:

```
@foreach($clientesConMensajes as $clienteConMensaje)
    {{ $clienteConMensaje->propiedadClienteUno }}
    {{ $clienteConMensaje->propiedadClienteN }}
    @foreach($clienteConMensaje->mensajesDeUsuarios as $mensajeDeUsuario)
    {{ $mensajeDeUsuario->pivot->propiedadMensajeUno }}
    {{ $mensajeDeUsuario->pivot->propiedadMensajeN }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Recuerda que:

- Tanto la propiedad `propiedadMensajeUno` como `propiedadMensajeN` son las columnas extra de la tabla *pivot* que deseas mostrar y que para poder acceder a ellas debes declararlas como argumentos en el método `withPivot`

Comment: Ya esta solucionado, lo puse en mi pregunta, no habia que iterar otra vez más solo acceder a `{{ $item->pivot->mensaje }}` y ya solucionado. Mil gracias @BetaM

Comment: No no! realmete lo tuyo es lo que a sido valido. Solo que yo no estaba iterando de forma correcta por no saber acceder a los datos de `pivot` no he tenido que hacer nada más, todo lo tuyo a sido lo correcto, por eso te digo

Comment: @Miguel listo tenías razón creí que había puesto el acceso a `pivot` (*no vi bien*), he replicado tu ejercicio y con la propuesta en mi respuesta ya debería funcionar

Comment: Perfecto! Ahora si que si!